# OpenCV Constants.CaptureProperty

Tags: java, opencv

Hi I use OpenCV Java and have some problem.

I open video file and try get property like FPS.
And others:

- CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC
- CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT

So first I opened video like this:

`VideoCapture vC = new VideoCapture(url2);`

and next i have a problem with function

```
vC.get(int i)
```

in OpenCV C++ its look like

```
vC.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
```

In Java where I find this constants?In HighGui I didnt find them. Only what I find is another libary to OpenCV where are this constants http://siggiorn.com/wp-content/uploads/libraries/opencv-java/docs/sj/opencv/Constants.CaptureProperty.html. But where I find them in OpenCV Java. Anyway how I have to use vC.get() function? Maybe some working example?

Comment: Not familiar with the library, shouldn't there be documentation on the function (or interface) to show what values for this `int` argument mean? Have you tried using the values contained in that other library to see if they do what you want?

Answer (score 8):

There is a [bug report](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3460) about this issue.

Until it is fixed, I suggest that you find these constants in the C++ source code, and define them yourself.

Edit:

I was just curious myself. You find them in the file modules/highgui/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp They are:

```
   CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC       =0,
   CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES     =1,
   CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO  =2,
   CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH    =3,
   CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT   =4,
   CAP_PROP_FPS            =5,
   CAP_PROP_FOURCC         =6,
   CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT    =7,
   CAP_PROP_FORMAT         =8,
   CAP_PROP_MODE           =9,
   CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS    =10,
   CAP_PROP_CONTRAST      =11,
   CAP_PROP_SATURATION    =12,
   CAP_PROP_HUE           =13,
   CAP_PROP_GAIN          =14,
   CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE      =15,
   CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB   =16,
   CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE_BLUE_U =17,
   CAP_PROP_RECTIFICATION =18,
   CAP_PROP_MONOCROME     =19,
   CAP_PROP_SHARPNESS     =20,
   CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE =21, // DC1394: exposure control done by camera, user can adjust refernce level using this feature
   CAP_PROP_GAMMA         =22,
   CAP_PROP_TEMPERATURE   =23,
   CAP_PROP_TRIGGER       =24,
   CAP_PROP_TRIGGER_DELAY =25,
   CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE_RED_V =26,
   CAP_PROP_ZOOM          =27,
   CAP_PROP_FOCUS         =28,
   CAP_PROP_GUID          =29,
   CAP_PROP_ISO_SPEED     =30,
   CAP_PROP_BACKLIGHT     =32,
   CAP_PROP_PAN           =33,
   CAP_PROP_TILT          =34,
   CAP_PROP_ROLL          =35,
   CAP_PROP_IRIS          =36,
   CAP_PROP_SETTINGS      =37
```

Comment: To use, seems you'll have to recompile.  You can't just call:  aVideoCapture.cap.get( valueOfTheConstantHere). In the link @Matthias included, 'Peter Meier' reports that after he "recompiled the whole thing" the constant  'CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT' worked, whereas trying it without the recompile gives error: "HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L2: Unable to get property <unknown property string>(7) - Invalid argument"    (Same error for  other constants tried)

Answer (score 3):

use class `import org.opencv.videoio.Videoio`;

```
vc.open(FD.class.getResource("1.avi").getPath());
double totalFrameNumber = vc.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);  
System.out.println("\n"+totalFrameNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the bug is [solved](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/4667). Now you should be able to use it as:

```
VideoCapture vC = new VideoCapture(...);
nbFrames = vC.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
```

Comment: I have tried like this. but it is not working. Can you help me please?

_VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture("/home/aritra/workspace/oopencv/horror.mp4");
  
  if(!capture.isOpened()){
   System.out.println("could not open this file ");
  }
  else{
   System.out.println("lingth"+(capture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)));_