# How to get fps/frames per second of a videocapture object

Tags: java, opencv, timer, javacv

I am using a videocapture object to capture and process frames of a video in opencv/javacv.
I dont know how to get the frame rate.I want a timer that runs in the background during the live video capture.It should pause on a face being detected and continue later.
Due to the processing of haarcascade file,it is taking much time for each rame to process. how to adjust the frame rate.

```
   System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
   VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);
```

Comment: I don't know how to do that in java but in C/C++ I'll use , VideoCapture::get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)  take a look here : http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-get

Comment: Thanks i've seen this but not possible in java thats the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract various parameter from VideoCapture like frame rate, frame height, frame width etc.

```
cv::VideoCapture input_video;
 if(input_video.open(my_device))
 {
    std::cout<<"Video file open "<<std::endl;
 }
 else
 {
    std::cout<<"Not able to Video file open "<<std::endl;

 }
int fps = input_video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
int frameCount = input_video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
double fheight = input_video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
double fwidth = input_video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
 VideoCapture VC = new VideoCapture(0);

//First you requried open Camera.

VC.open();

//Now for geting 'Frame per secand"

VC.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS); // it returns FPS(Frame per secand)

//Now for seting 'Frame per secand"

VC.set(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FPS,10.0);//in this 10.0 is value for FPS,its double value.
VC.relase();
```

Answer (score 1):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066875/opencv-constants-captureproperty#answer-21066952) helps me. There is a list of constants and their values. Just put value to VideoCapture's `get()` method. Ex. `videoCapture.get(5)`, will return `FPS` of video.