# CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT is not available in opencv for java

Tags: java, c++, opencv

I am trying to transform C++ program into a java program.
There are a few lines I can't transform:

```
long totalFrameNumber = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frameToStart-3);
double rate = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); 
cvtColor( frame,fgray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
```

These macros ,`CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT`, `CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES`, `CV_CAP_PROP_FPS`, `CV_BGR2GRAY` ,cannot be found in the `OpenCV` for Java.
What should I do?

Comment: Please use the edit link below your question and use its "code formatting" feature to clearly distinguish your machine code/text from your question text.

Comment: Potential Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066875/opencv-constants-captureproperty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV Constants.CaptureProperty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066875/opencv-constants-captureproperty)

Answer (score 0):

How are you?

I'm not sure but you should write CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT not CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).