# How to get the number of frames captured in a video stream?

Tags: java, opencv, video-processing

I need to get the number of frames captured of a video using OpenCV with Java. I'm capturing the video through a webcam. I tried to use:

```
CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC
```

in `capture.get()` but it seems like it is not working. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066875/opencv-constants-captureproperty) but didn't get any successful way to do this. I'm using OpenCV 2.4.8. Can anyone please give me any idea of how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post your code and your output :)

Comment: not supported for webcam feed. do your own counting

Comment: @Constantine Actually the code doesn't include anything regarding the capture.get(). Because I'm using this video to train a model and use it to predict a class for each frame using SVM trained model.what I'm trying to do is to capture video for 15sec. get the features for each frame, predict the class for each frame and depending on the predicted values for time period of 15 seconds, give a Boolean value true or false. Anyway thank you for replying :)