# Cant Open a video using opencv in java

Tags: java, opencv, ubuntu-17.04

I am using *opencv 320* *in ubuntu 17.04* and  simply trying to count total frame numbers of a given video in java.Here is my code.

```
    public class VideoAnalysis {

        public static void main (String [] args){

            System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
File f = new File("/home/aritra/workspace/oopencv/horror.mp4");
        boolean b = f.exists();

        System.out.println(b);

            VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture("/home/aritra/workspace/oopencv/horror.mp4");

            if(!capture.isOpened()){
                System.out.println("could not open this file ");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("length"+(capture.get(Videoio.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)));
            }

        }   
    }
```

I have kept the video file in the project. Whenever I run this program it is showing message

```
    true
Failed to query video capabilities: Inappropriate ioctl for device
libv4l2: error getting capabilities: Inappropriate ioctl for device
VIDEOIO ERROR: V4L: device /home/aritra/workspace/oopencv/horror.mp4: Unable to query number of channels
could not open this file
```

But my video I/O status is

```
Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  NO
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 57.64.101)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 57.56.101)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 55.34.101)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 4.2.100)
--       avresample:                YES (ver 3.1.0)
--     GStreamer:                   NO
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     Aravis SDK:                  NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.12.3) / libv4l2 (ver 1.12.3)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
```

I have checked [OpenCV Constants.CaptureProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066875/opencv-constants-captureproperty#answer-21066952) and make ***WITH_LIBV4L=ON*** according to https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/6157 But still getting these message. What should I do? Can any one help me?

Comment: your problem is (as far as I can tell) not linked to opencv, rather to your opening of the file. most likely, you're trying to load the file from a wrong path

Comment: I have edited my program and this time tried with full path _"/home/aritra/workspace/oopencv/horror.mp4"_ but I am getting same message

Comment: seeing as that is not a full path ... anyway, try just File f = new File(myPath); boolean b = f.exists(); or something similar, check the value of b, and if it's false, check the full path of f.

Comment: @Stultuske I have updated my question. And according to your suggestion I have also checked my path. It is returning true.